# GXT : Grid row editing ,not working with non editable field/column

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am creating the row editing grid now it has a column called name which is **not editable** how ever its content is string and the icon so those icons are rendered based on values inside my Model.As soon as  I start editing the field which has name column shows object instead of Name and icons.I tried using renderer

following is the code snippet

```
GridRowEditing<Model> editing = new CustomGridRowEditing<Model>(grid);
ColumnConfig<Model, Model> nameColumn = new ColumnConfig<Model, Model>(
            new IdentityValueProvider<Model>("name"), 165,
            "Name");
editing.addRenderer(nameColumn,new AbstractSafeHtmlRenderer<Model>() {

        @Override
        public SafeHtml render(Model value) {
            SafeHtmlBuilder sb =  new SafeHtmlBuilder();
            String type = value.getType();
            if("Owner".equals(type )){
              sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div  class='Owner' id='"
                            + value.getName()
                            "'>");
            } else {
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div  class='Employee' id='"
                            + value.getName()
                            "'>");
            }
            return sb.toSafeHtml();
        }
    } );

    editing.startEditing(new GridCell(5, 0));
```

when the row is editable the the name field value are replaced with com.myapp.Model.Please help me out.

Comment: You should post the code of `CustomGridRowEditing`, since it's not a GXT class (and I guess it's the place where the magic happens)

Comment: Are you using the CheckBoxSelectionModel for this grid?

Comment: no @AndyKing.. got the answer Model is the cause.